# In wildfly, how do I disable Stateful Bean Passivation without using the EJB3.2-specific "passivationCapable=false"

Tags: wildfly, ejb-3.1, stateful-session-bean, ejb-passivation

I have set up cluster. I am using EJB 3.1 in my project. Can I somehow disable Stateful Session Bean passivation?

Comment: Hi Marinos An, did you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: @TT Unfortunately no